# Who came up with the Darwinian demon?

Tags: terminology, evolution, darwin

I know of Maxwell's, Descartes' and Laplace's demons but I recently found out that there is Darwinian one. I do not think that this demon appears in the works of Charles Darwin. Do you know who may have coined the term (Darwin's/Darwinian demon)?

This article: U. Kutschera & K. J. Niklas *[Darwin-Wallace Demons: survival of the fastest in populations of duckweeds and the evolutionary history of an enigmatic group of angiosperms](https://doi.org/10.1111/plb.12171)* (2014) says it was R. Law *[Optimal life histories under age-specific predation](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.1086/283488)* The American Naturalist (1979). But I have found various earlier sources.

The earliest English source I could find is [Colin S. Pittendrigh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colin_Pittendrigh)'s *[On temporal organization in living systems](http://nicorg.pbworks.com/f/Pittendrigh%20Temporal%20Organization.pdf)* - Harvey lectures, 1961, in relation to the works of German E. Bünning. So maybe it appears first in another language? Also I am suspicious that such a concept was invented for a lecture.

Comment: This idea seems to be related to Anaximander's evolution in which he proposed that god-like beings would arise out of the Apeiron. This probably doesn't help you much, but it's another "demon" for you to think about which is identical.